# clearTimeout in componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set timeout each time when user's reaction is awaited.
If a user clicked, setTimeout should be cleared. 
So, I'm trying to get an ID of setTimeout to be able to use it in clearTimeout(ID).
The first way to get an ID envokes userFailedInTime() and I have one more point of computerScore.
The second way doesn't work as I see.

Please, how to clear timeout properly?

```
class MyContainer extends React.Component{
state = {
    computerScore: 0,
 }

componentDidMount() {

    // The first way to get timeOut ID
    this.failID = this.userFailedInTime();

     // The second way to get timeOut ID
     this.userFailedInTime = this.userFailedInTime.bind(this);
  }

  userFailedInTime() {
    return setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        catched: "",
        active: getRandom(),
        computerScore: this.state.computerScore + 1
      });
    }, this.state.delay);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){

    if(
        // Some conditional
    ){
        // The first way to clear timeout I've tried but it fires userFailedInTime
        // in componentDidMount() and sets computerScore 1 point higher which is not what I want
        clearTimeout(this.failID);
        this.userFailedInTime()

         // The second way to clear timeout I've tried seems doesn't work
         clearTimeout(this.userFailedInTime());
         this.userFailedInTime()
    }

  }


render(){
    return (
        // Some code
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you are calling userFailedInTime you are creating a new timeout. The important part here is that it is a new timeout, even if you call it multiple times you won't get the same timeout. Meaning you are not clearing the timeout you are setting.

Instead store the timeout in the state or as a class variable

```
userFailedInTime() {
  this.state.userTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
      catched: "",
      active: getRandom(),
      computerScore:   this.state.computerScore + 1
    });
  }, this.state.delay);
}
```

And then clear it with

```
clearTimeout(this.state.userTimeout)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your approach is the failID is not being updated. You need to update it when you call `userFailedInTime` method

```
componentDidUpdate(){

    if(
        // Some conditional
    ){
        // The first way to clear timeout I've tried but it fires userFailedInTime
        // in componentDidMount() and sets computerScore 1 point higher which is not what I want
        clearTimeout(this.failID);
        this.failID = this.userFailedInTime()
    }

  }
```

In the second case

```
 clearTimeout(this.userFailedInTime());
 this.userFailedInTime()
```

you are executing the `userFailedInTime` method twice, once the `setTimeout` is cleared with the returned value but not the next time.